# Add additional source set to Gretty classpath

Tags: gradle, gretty

My project contains a `jar` and a `war` module. The `jar` module contains to source sets `main` and `generated`.

My `jar` module `gradle.build` defines the source sets as listed below:

```
sourceSets {
    generated
    main {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.generated.output  // adds the sourceSet to the compileClassPath
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.generated.output  // adds the sourceSet to the runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

and places the output of both source sets into the jar.

```
jar {
    from sourceSets.generated.output
    from sourceSets.main.output
}
```

Within my `war` module I'd like to use Gretty to run it within the build. The `build.gradle` file looks like this.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/gretty.gradle"

gretty {
    // supported values:
    // 'jetty7', 'jetty8', 'jetty9', 'tomcat7', 'tomcat8'
    servletContainer = 'tomcat8'

    httpPort = 8081
    contextPath = '/wbc'
    realm 'wbc-realm'
    realmConfigFile 'tomcat-users.xml'
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':interfaces')

    compile "org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:${atmosphereVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}"
    compile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${servletVersion}"

    runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${slf4jVersion}"
    runtime "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
}
```

Whenever I start Gretty using `gradle --daemon clean appRun` Gretty fails to start up Tomcat due to a `ClassNotFoundException`. That class is located in the `generated` source set of my `jar` module. How can I tell gretty to add it to the classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the output directories of generated to gretty classPath:

```
gretty {
  ...
  sourceSets.generated.output.each { classPath it }
}
```